# Follow tree structure of sql database with python

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have a database with structure like this:

| Mother | Child1 | Child2 | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x123 | 0x456 | 0x789 | 80 |
| 0x456 | 0xabc | null | 60 |
| 0x789 | null | null | 50 |
| 0xabc | 0xdef | 0xghi | 120 |

And this database can extend upto thousands of records
Is there a way to give some name like "0x123" to a Python function and get sum of all his/her children's salary?

Like 0x123 => 230

0x456 => 180

0x789 => 50

Comment: The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract the contents of your database as a flat table like this, then cycle over the records to build a `graph` in a module like [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/)

In the below, I setup a pandas dataframe to host the data, but for you, you'd need to deal with whatever database api you've chosen:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx


df = pd.DataFrame([{"Mother" : '0x123', 
                   "Child1" : '0x456', 
                   "Child2" : '0x789', 
                   "Salary" : 80},
                  
                  {"Mother" : '0x456', 
                   "Child1" : '0xabc', 
                   "Child2" : None, 
                   "Salary" : 60},
                   
                   {"Mother" : '0x789', 
                   "Child1" : None, 
                   "Child2" : None, 
                   "Salary" : 50},
                   
                   {"Mother" : '0xabc', 
                   "Child1" : '0xdef', 
                   "Child2" : '0xghi', 
                   "Salary" : 120},
                  ], 
                 
                 )

graph = nx.DiGraph()

for e, r in df.iterrows():
    graph.add_node(r.Mother, data={"salary" : r.Salary})
    if r.Child1 is not None:
        graph.add_edge(r.Mother, r.Child1)
    if r.Child2 is not None:
        graph.add_edge(r.Mother, r.Child2)
```

This will instantiate your graph, for the above data, the graph looks like this:

[image]

Once instantiated, you can then extract details such as all the descendants of a given node.

e.g.

```
summary=[]
start_node = '0x456'
node_set = nx.descendants(graph, start_node)
node_set.add(start_node)
for node,data in graph.nodes(data=True):
    print(data)
    if node in node_set:
        summary.append(data.get('data',{}).get('salary',0))
```

Which you can finally use to calculate your tree-based figure:

```
summary
```

Which returns:

```
>>> [60, 120, 0, 0]
```

So summing this:

```
sum(summary)
```

Finally returns:

```
>>> 180
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea which database you are using and on which libraries you have knowledge about. However, I will share my rough solution (this function will only give you some hints about the solution, structure depends on libraries you use).

I believe the function you need has to be a recursive function.

```
def your_func(node):
    child_1 = node.child_1
    child_2 = node.child_2
    return your_func(child_1).salary + your_func(child_2).salary
```

You will need a stop condition for this function. That condition will stop the function when it reaches a leaf node (node with no child). Like I said, you have to modify it for your own purposes and with respect to the libraries you use, it is like a pseudocode more than a Python script.